# About "spark.sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

During running one of Spark Stage,

I face the unexpected error log on executors, and stage is not working anymore.

Could anyone tell me what happened if below message is occurred?

and is there any limitation to set this setting value? (spark.sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold)

```sh
# encountered message on executor
21/04/29 07:25:58 INFO ObjectAggregationIterator: Aggregation hash map size 128 reaches threshold capacity (128 entries), spilling and falling back to sort based aggregation. You may change the threshold by adjust option spark.sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold

21/04/29 07:26:51 INFO PythonUDFRunner: Times: total = 87019, boot = -361, init = 380, finish = 87000
21/04/29 07:26:51 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_36_1765 stored as values in memory (estimated size 19.6 MB, free 5.2 GB)
21/04/29 07:26:53 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 2154, boot = 6, init = 1, finish = 2147
21/04/29 07:26:53 INFO Executor: Finished task 1765.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 11172). 5310 bytes result sent to driver
21/04/29 07:27:33 INFO PythonUDFRunner: Times: total = 93086, boot = -461, init = 480, finish = 93067
21/04/29 07:27:33 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_36_1792 stored as values in memory (estimated size 19.7 MB, free 5.2 GB)
21/04/29 07:27:35 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 1999, boot = -40047, init = 40051, finish = 1995
21/04/29 07:27:35 INFO Executor: Finished task 1792.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 11199). 5267 bytes result sent to driver
21/04/29 07:27:35 INFO PythonUDFRunner: Times: total = 97305, boot = -313, init = 350, finish = 97268
21/04/29 07:27:35 INFO MemoryStore: Block rdd_36_1789 stored as values in memory (estimated size 19.7 MB, free 5.3 GB)
21/04/29 07:27:37 INFO PythonRunner: Times: total = 1928, boot = -2217, init = 2220, finish = 1925
21/04/29 07:27:37 INFO Executor: Finished task 1789.0 in stage 6.0 (TID 11196). 5310 bytes result sent to driver
```

```py
# about Spark Stage I did
# 
# given dataframe is
# (uid is given by monotonically_increasing_id)
# |-------|-------|
# | uids  | score |
# |-------|-------|
# |[1,2,3]| 50    |
# |[1,2]  | 70    |
# |[1]    | 90    |
#
# expected result
# |-------|-------|
# | uid   | score |
# |-------|-------|
# | 1     | 90    |
# | 2     | 70    |
# | 3     | 50    |

rdd = df.select(F.explode('uids').alias('uid'), 'score') \
        .rdd.map(lambda x: (x['uid'], x)) \
        .reduceByKey(func=max, numPartitions=1800) \
        .cache()
```

Comment: There is no error in the log snippet you have supplied. Also, perhaps you want `x['score']` instead of `x` as the second element of the pair? (I would personally stick with the DataFrame API and use `groupBy('uid').max('score')` )

Comment: Thank you for your comment. What I found is that getting stuck in my job is related to `PythonUDFRunner`. (PythonUDFRunner took so much time, however, it's not related to my question.)

Comment: Anyway, what I want to clarify is that, there are 2 configurations, related to ObjectHashAggregate. With `spark.sql.execution.useObjectHashAggregateExec`, we can turn on/off this feature. With `spark.sql.objectHashAggregate.sortBased.fallbackThreshold`, we can set default threshold. Then, what is the possible range of this value? (More than extremely big value?)

Comment: Probably best to close the question then.